# Typescript, narrowing nested generic types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, nested-generics

I am building a type safe form schema.  One of the form entries needs perform keyof checking of a subset of the form type. I am at a loss how to pass & narrow the generic type to the sub type.

Here is a link to ts playground where I have tried to work out a simple version of what I am working on. [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEwCrmgXigImBAD2AFo4A7MAV2BygB9czKBbAIwgCdaGdkOB7MMn4B3Mt1wBjABYRJAa1b8COANwAodaEiwEKKNgDe6qFEQBDdogBcUAM7AO5AOYbT2iLfhI0GDQF8NLQxdHwA5c2YIAB5UAD4DKFQAbXkIEH4AMySAXShCfDJkOygACnJMzigASQBKZLyAfhqoWzIIADdOII9QlABBDg5zEFiEoxMoD1sccyGRtUnnAUowABlLJFsHJzJXScy9YtsAJTl+DmRotIzs7xQIqLGoADJ7RxcAGj7kOICekIAZRkEGY5nuV3iiQh9B+g2Go3iAJ0wNkYOe2DOkguVxuWSS31RoPBRzGf00vRgF2YiWMphEF3kmUQokenneu32pjgyDaLHYHDcUA4lEQEDstkMwtFEDZ2w+e1UUDgdn6kmAcC6tiU-DF5jISpFYuqvKgTDYVX8DSFnAEHAlUCltouco5LiVKrVGq1UB1eoN+SGFxNfItHCgVpy-002LIDigmWpRLBtmT5miVI4zHGjsmDI4TJZIldUumuHwRFIFGoOG+FisMzZtH8n0mPMlUwwM3NAtrZk2NlwJubrdMRvFksm7i7uDmCNrU6gy34qw2DdwJxldgXplMhx8Drpu7HMpL-fXOE3YqgTe+ZbwBSrVBoEdHx+VqvVmvZUvrWyHJRet+fb3iCChKCor6Liexqmr+A4zFe0DDneM44D2nAjouLaTDhpjOva1hHtOkDWLM8wgDuu7LquCE4AAokG9pUXuRwSsRu4EXKhh-jYDFMTekQQCBXYPpW5DPjgeHvp6X5ajxdHVIBcnCahpE4GBijKFJb7HgRIYKQ2-F2jUyAiepGFcP42G4eogTqEAA)

Specifically I want the `fields` properties of the `FieldArray` to be type safe. The same way that the Schema type is.  I am at a loss as to how to narrow or even pass the type for `fields`

```
type FieldType = "text-input" | "number" | "dropdown" | "checkbox";

type Field = {
  label: string;
  type: FieldType;
};

type FieldName<T> = T[keyof T] extends (infer I)[] ? I : never;

type FieldArray<T> = {
  type: "array";
  groupLabel: string;
  fields: Record<keyof FieldName<T> & string, Field>;
};

type SchemaField<T> = Field | FieldArray<T>;

type Schema<T> = Record<keyof T, SchemaField<T>>;

type Form = {
  workflowName: string;
  id: number;
  rules: { ruleName: string; isActive: boolean; ruleId: number }[];
  errors: { errorName: string; isActive: boolean; errorId: number }[];
};

const formSchema: Schema<Form> = {
  workflowName: { type: "text-input", label: "Name" },
  id: { type: "number", label: "Id" },
  rules: {
    type: "array",
    groupLabel: "Rules",
    fields: {
      ruleName: { label: "Rule Name", type: "text-input" },
      isActive: { label: "Is Active", type: "checkbox" },
      ruleId: { label: "Rule Id", type: "number" },
    },
  },
  errors: {
    type: "array",
    groupLabel: "Errors",
    fields: {
      errorName: { label: "Error Name", type: "text-input" },
      isActive: { label: "Is Active", type: "checkbox" },
      errorId: { label: "Error Id", type: "number" },
    },
  },
};
```

I expect the fields property of `rules` and `errors` to be type safe against their definition in `Form`

Here's an example of how this is not type safe.  In the above I can put any properties in the fields object of `errors`

the fields object for `errors` should only be allowed to contain the keys `errorName`, `isActive`, `errorId` as per the definition.  But the below entries do not trigger a type warning.

```
errors: {

    fields: {
      foo: { label: "Error Name", type: "text-input" },
      bar: { label: "Is Active", type: "checkbox" },
      baz: { label: "Error Id", type: "number" },
    },
  },
```

Comment: are all five keys `ruleName`, `isActive`, `ruleId`, `errorName` and `errorId` valid for both `fields` objects?

Comment: Could you demonstrate how these things are and are not type safe? Ideally a [mre] would give an obvious issue (e.g., an error where you don't expect one or vice versa), and some details about how we can understand what values should and should not be valid `Schema<T>`s for a given `T`.

Comment: Like, *maybe* [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WG47ow) is what you're going for, but I'd need quite a bit more use case information to be sure.  If it's what you expect, then I could write it up.  But if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I have updated the question with a specific area that is not type safe.

Comment: @jcalz Yes!  Your playground link seems to be what I am tryin to do!

Comment: I will write up an answer when I get a chance... might be a few hours from now.  In the meantime, please double check that my suggestion meets your needs first; I'd hate to write up a long answer and then find out that there's some fundamental use case it doesn't satisfy

Comment: Yes, it also nicely knows if the form definition is an array type and enforces that on the schema.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your code example, my inclination would be to define `Schema<T>` as follows:

```
type Schema<T> = { [K in keyof T]: SchemaProp<T[K]> };

type SchemaProp<T> = T extends readonly (infer U)[] ?
  { type: "array", groupLabel: string, fields: Schema<U> }
  : { type: FieldType, label: string }
```

Instead of using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) in which there is no correlation between the particular keys in `K` and the corresponding values in `V`, I've made it a structure-preserving [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where each key `K` in `keyof T` is mapped to the property type `SchemaProp<T[K]>`.

And `SchemaProp<T>` takes a property type `T` and converts it into the corresponding "field" type.  It checks, via [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html), whether `T` is an array with element type `U`; if so, then it becomes an `"array"`-typed field where the `fields` property is itself a `Schema<U>`.  Therefore `Schema<T>` is a *recursive* type, meaning that, if you wanted, you could represent schemas of types which contain arrays of arrays, or arrays of arrays of arrays.  If the property `T` is not an array, then you get just one of the `FieldType`-typed fields.

---

Let's make sure this works:

```
const goodFormSchema: Schema<Form> = {
  workflowName: { type: "text-input", label: "Name" },
  id: { type: "number", label: "Id" },
  rules: {
    type: "array",
    groupLabel: "Rules",
    fields: {
      ruleName: { label: "Rule Name", type: "text-input" },
      isActive: { label: "Is Active", type: "checkbox" },
      ruleId: { label: "Rule Id", type: "number" },
    },
  },
  errors: {
    type: "array",
    groupLabel: "Errors",
    fields: {
      errorName: { label: "Error Name", type: "text-input" },
      isActive: { label: "Is Active", type: "checkbox" },
      errorId: { label: "Error Id", type: "number" }
    }
  }
}; // okay
```

So that works, and if we put the wrong keys in for one of the `fields` properties, we'll see an appropriate error:

```
const badFormSchema: Schema<Form> = {
  workflowName: { type: "text-input", label: "Name" },
  id: { type: "number", label: "Id" },
  rules: {
    type: "array",
    groupLabel: "Rules",
    fields: {
      ruleName: { label: "Rule Name", type: "text-input" },
      isActive: { label: "Is Active", type: "checkbox" },
      ruleId: { label: "Rule Id", type: "number" },
    },
  },
  errors: {
    type: "array",
    groupLabel: "Errors",
    fields: {
      foo: { label: "Error Name", type: "text-input" }, // error!
      // Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'foo' does not exist in type ...
      bar: { label: "Is Active", type: "checkbox" },
      baz: { label: "Error Id", type: "number" },
    }
  }
};
```

---

Note that, depending on your use cases, you might want to modify that definition.

Maybe you will have an object type with a property that is another object type instead of an *array* of object types.  If so, you'd probably need another conditional check in `SchemaProp<T>`.  Or maybe you will have a property whose type is a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types), in which case you'd probably need to make sure that `SchemaProp<T>` [distributes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) over such unions... or *doesn't* distribute, depending on your needs.

Thorough testing is recommended.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYglhANgEwCrmgXigImBAD2AFo4A7MAV2BygB9czKBbAIwgCdaGdkOB7MMn4B3Mt1wBjABYRJAa1b8COANwAodaEhQAyjIjMAhgB5UAPijYA3lADaAaSjko8iCH4AzKKgC6ALj0DYwAFATAzR19LAF8NLQwg2VDws0tMdSgfKEJ8MmQAZygOCCNhMkQQKAAKck9OKABVAEo7XygAfihbbQhAnCMODiMQHAAaKABzAUowABkjdkRAguAOckmJzwQUAsD9ZNNG2Kh-TKgAegvs3Ih8ov5WACs5YE7uqF7+x5fJGi2doV9sFTBYoDFTpdrsYQOwoB5KFAREYyG9gNI4AVzj0MIF4Eg0BgJohFkgVmsNuDNAkdDB+BxmFZuucRPT5J5EKIAHJGZh9KCrdZkSYaLJwZCBJhsTii4qURAQPYfDjyiA8vnkoUi5wFACCfzgADd+Up+AqUao5QqAJISqBS9gccFtWWcAQcJW2N309X8wUbS2Y-XAI0m-hm0pkS3eji2yUsR3O3waOKaXpJQxGOkMpkHTMmbPMczqC4AKk+iTzxkLTOs5yyrI47M5Il9gTrWU7na+sEB6Egsq7WRJS01Afr4MHzjtHaHWR7+JQ-YgU67I7JAopwqnqa7KoVnonXZ7AyGIzUR87034swWo83WtXne2BKVVdMs7ne9VbYf46-Q5BgaxqBKa5pRpec77hAcb2gmMqQeC5g7lOMaHgBJ6DMMoxPlk163qSyx-tuiEvrswKHCYn4ATkQw+ryfpbiKiFdkBIYgVAYGRrhQ4xrBDoIQBMTIROqYQqWFzUpI-BkKsUCePSzDvhR+aFukzINmyHLcgx7YVpA-T4EQpAUNQ4xQOuRE4L6tAxGM5zinpJ4CVwxKEf0tq2fZWTQeh3a4rgWHnt5V4zPM7m4AASqqBTjBOZFAhpQ7Qb+tiWf00UKlANkTCeRkkOQVA0OCIWsXqwH8mlEU4NaRTBqG5kngYChKCoJWXtBsFVfeOCZdAnm5QFOAuV5okhXZ5xoe2E6YWeoylVMYV3huOAAKJ0R6cVdglfldjGqUWdV63utlDGNUN+UmUVo1zmxoZ6eluC1VA9XGudBlSLILXKDdvEbV1h09cd9JQAN+n8sN8FcFSXYxOccNxFCUD8PIIyaNJslvKwZSFspGbGAWinqbOjbNjpGofHluRXWZbk9TZ7VijO4P9CNdMrZ5jNWoq03HkNQXzRO+HhT1fWxQtO288lP66R8j29aqp18u9EOXYVZlc2Vr2VYDHN1RVKv9M1ig-Zrnadcz8t9aDyCG4wUO-VkE1OyFU1JfO-NzVtoU3iLK3A5tEuArtz7hg9R0bUrEB23g1Pq8VdlIzGACEl5XFAADyzyvBZcD4MMiBQDCyMVFUBSQJIcCeFU8hkKIZBQGA4ScCGioTCiyBQAA5Ap-Bd1AwiKva-BvIQmJvC46YAHQz5e2McOHPXPdrMfG61judtjABei-+5HYPOQ7Ztw076ipuoQA)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation.  This works for my use case and helps me better understand how to solve similar issues in the future.